# Finding a series of common multiples given arbitrary numbers

Tags: least-common-multiple

So there are accepted methods for computing the lowest common multiple given 2 or more numbers.

However I'm been thinking about how to compute/enumerate a set/series of common multiple integers from the lowest common multiple integer to infinity or a limit such as "m < M" (where m is one of the common multiple integers and M is some arbitrary limit set to perhaps 1546).

Is there a an algorithm or formula for this?

Comment: Really unclear what you mean here. Can you clarify? Where is randomness used?

Comment: I mean 34, 546, 5678, randomly chosen numbers.

Comment: Do you mean randomly, or just abitrary? The language used in this sentence is still unclear: "However I'm been thinking about how to compute a series of common multiples from the lowest common multiple to infinite or a limit like "CM < 1546" (where CM is the common multiple)." Something is missing here.

Comment: Are you interested in enumerating all common multiples $m$ of a set of numbers with $m<M$, with $M$ some arbitrary upper bound?

Comment: Yes that is correct. @JackM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The least common multiple of a set of numbers divides *every* common multiple of those numbers. *Proof:* if $m$ is the least common multiple and $qm+r$, $0\leq r<m$ is some other common multiple, then $r$ is also a common multiple, thus $r=0$ since $m$ is the *least* common multiple.

Therefore, given an upper bound $M$, to find all common multiples less than $M$, just find the least common multiple and then list all multiples of that which are less than $M$.

Comment: Awesome thanks. It makes sense. But I'm not quite getting the significance of `qm + r`, how did you come up with that? Why is `r` also a common multiple?

Comment: If `qm + r` is a linear equation that graphs a set of common multiples, then I understand `0 <= r < m`. This r constant cannot be greater than m. I also understand that 0 is a common multiple of all numbers. What I'm not quite understanding is how you proved that `qm + r` has to equal some other common multiple.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai I'm simply [dividing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) an arbitrary common multiple by $m$. $r$ must also be a common multiple because $qm+r$ is, and $qm$ is (because $m$ is), thus subtracting the two we must get another common multiple.